# Can you use add_filter() inside other function?

Tags: filters

I'm new to WordPress, and currently developing my first plugin and currently having difficulties.

How I can insert the add_filter action inside my submit function? I want the `add_filter` action to process after the user click the submit button.

I have try this but it didn't work.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {

    function addContent($content = '') {            
        $content .= "My content";

        return $content;
    }

    add_filter('the_content', 'addContent');
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you've solved this problem (as stated in comments blow), please post your solution as an answer for others.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're ACTUALLY looking to do is to [`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters). [`add_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) registers a new filter, whereas [`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) does the filters that have been registered.

If that's not what you're looking to do, then you need to be aware that [`add_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) needs to be run every time you want the filter applied. This allows plugins to be removed without having to unregister all their filters and generally keeps a wordpress install pretty clean...it also helps with security. A better question might encompass a broader scope, where you state what you're trying to do, rather than having us try and troubleshoot your implementation of it.

Comment: I want to add content at the bottom of every post of my site, and add_filter did it, but add_filter() action only process when the plugin is activated, but how about if I want it to process after the submit button was click? Is apply_filters() will work? I already read the documentaion about apply_filters() and I  didn't find the solution to my question.

Comment: I just want to say that I solved this already. I separate the addContent function from submit function and put a line of code inside submit function that calls the function to add contents.


something like this:

`function addContent($content = '') {
         $content .= "My content";
         return $content; 
}

add_filter('the_content', 'addContent'); 

if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
   $content .= addContent();
}`

this works for me.. thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want it to only show up once a button has been clicked and then go away on the next page chance (once the post data is gone), then what you're doing is an appropriate method. If you want to change the behavior permanently when the button is clicked, you will need to store the option in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write in the following way:

```
    function addContent($content = '') {    
     $content .= "My content";    
     return $content; 
    }

   if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
    add_filter('the_content', 'addContent'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shaon, Thanks for your reply. I couldn't get that to work efefctively, but here is a very workable function I found:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15311#comment:13